# Running process that has space characters in its path name with emacs on Windows 7

Tags: windows, emacs, f#

For F# mode in emacs, one need the following line in .emacs.
The problem is that because of space between file path, C-c C-s doesn't work.

```
(setq fsharp-compiler "C:/Program Files/Microsoft F#/v4.0/fsc.exe")
```

I had to copy the F# compilers to the directory that doesn't have space in its file path.

```
(setq fsharp-compiler "C:/app/fsharp/fsc.exe")
```

How to run a process that has a space in its path name with emacs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, make sure you have a recent version of the F# mode (that was a bug fixed in June). Then, follow the instructions in the README file!

This line is given as an example:
`(setq fsharp-compiler "\"c:\\Program Files\\Microsoft F#\\v4.0\\Fsc.exe\"")`

Comment: (setq fsharp-compiler "\"c:/Program Files/Microsoft F#/v4.0/Fsc.exe\"") also works. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using %20 in place of space?
So the statement becomes

```
(setq fsharp-compiler "C:/Program Files/Microsoft%20F#/v4.0/fsc.exe")
```

I haven't tried it though but it works with the file import.
like the following works,

```
[[file:C:\Users\siddh\Downloads\Google%20Chrome\joker#.jpg]]
```

this also works

```
[[file:C:\Users\siddh\Downloads\Google Chrome\joker#.jpg]]
```

Just sharing my input. Hope it helps.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27947791)

Comment: @OrAssayag: This isn't a new question. Siddhesh is asking if the OP has tried something, and then outlines a suggestion. It could be rephrased declaratively as, "URL encode your spaces."